# ngOnChanges not firing when attribute changed by Observable/subscrption

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to do something after an `Observable`/`subscribe` completes. I'm changing an `Input` property in the `subscribe( onNext )` method, but `ngOnChanges` never fires.

What should I be doing differently?

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, 
  OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges,
  Input, Output
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'
    , providers: [ NamesService ]
})

export class MyPage  {
  @Input() names: any[];

  constructor( public namesSvc: NamesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getNames$()
  }


  getNames$() : void {
    this.nameService.get().subscribe( 
      (result)=>{
       this.names = result;
       console.log(`getNames$, names=${this.names}`);

       // I could doSomething() here, but it doesn't seem like the correct place
       // doSomething()  

      }
      , error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
    )
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) : void {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.warn(`>>> ngOnChanges triggered`)
    if (changes["names"]) {
      console.warn(`>>> ngOnChanges, names=${changes["names"]}`)
      this.doSomething()
    }
  }

  doSomething(){
    console.log("doing something");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's "as designed"

`ngOnChanges()` is only called when change detection updates a binding to an `@Input()`. If the input is changed imperatively from somewhere then it isn't called.

Just make `names` a getter/setter for code to be executed every time when the property is updated.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Günter it doesn't quite work like that from my understanding... When using [Observables](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/) you can trigger a change manually with the `Observable.next()` feature. The trick here is that you will have to return an `Observable` from your service- this can be done like so:

```
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx"; // remember the '/Rx', it got me...

export class NamesService {
    private initialNames: Array<string> = ["Joe", "Jack", "Pete"];

    get(){
        let names: Subject<Array<string>> = new Subject<Array<string>>();

        names.next(this.initialNames);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.initialNames.push('someOtherNames');
            names.next(this.initialNames);
        }, 1000);
        return names.asObservable();
    }
}
```

And then subscribe to it much as you have already done, and when the `.next()` runs it will trigger a change on the `.subscribe()` method.

I would recommend splitting this up from the get method though, you could possible have your own `onNameUpdate()` method that return the observable array- or something like that.