# Angular2: NgForm should be dirty but it is not

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Here is the **template**

```
          <time-shift-input 
            [start]="editingUser.defaultStart" 
            [startLabel]="'profile.defaultStart' | translate "
            [end]="editingUser.defaultEnd" 
            [endLabel]="'profile.defaultEnd' | translate "
            (onChange)="onShiftTimes($event)"></time-shift-input>
        <input type="hidden" name="defaultStart" [ngModel]="editingUser.defaultStart">
        <input type="hidden" name="defaultEnd" [ngModel]="editingUser.defaultEnd">
```

Here is the **component**

```
  onShiftTimes(e) {
   if ( !e.errors ) {
    this.editingUser.defaultStart = e.start;
    this.editingUser.defaultEnd = e.end;
  }
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe( () => {

    if ( this.profileForm.dirty ) {
      this.saveComponent.hasNew(true);
      if ( this.profileForm.valid ) {
        this.saveComponent.enabled = true;
      }
    } else {
      this.saveComponent.hasNew(false);
      this.saveComponent.enabled = false;
    }

   });
 }
```

time-shift-input component emits an event, component invokes onShiftTimes method, the form triggers valueChanges, however the form is still dirty:false, pristine:true

Why?

Comment: Can you check if `defaultStart` and `defaultEnd` actually get included in the form? Try and access the `controls` property of the parent `ngForm` object, or even access its `value` property and see if they're there. If they're not, it might have something to do with the fact they're hidden, or simply not 2-way bound.

Comment: After reading this – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913255/ngonchanges-not-firing-when-attribute-changed-by-observable-subscrption – I have added two setters for the two properties. And yes, when I print out form.value, the values are being updated as expected. As I am dealing with strings, I have even added `'' + this.editingUser.defaultStart` thus basically returning not the reference to the existing value but a new value. The problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the caveat and the solution.
Setting values programmatically won't trigger change detection, as marked elsewhere - [ngOnChanges not firing when attribute changed by Observable/subscrption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913255/ngonchanges-not-firing-when-attribute-changed-by-observable-subscrption)

After adding getters, though, the problem persisted and could be solved only after triggering `this.profileForm.control.markAsDirty()` implicitly. So in the example above,

```
  onShiftTimes(e) {
    if ( !e.errors ) {
     this.editingUser.defaultStart = e.start;
     this.editingUser.defaultEnd = e.end;
     this.profileForm.control.markAsDirty();
   }
  }
```

Cheers.