# Angular ngOnChanges in child doesn't trigger after subscribe manipulates data

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, angular2-observables, ngonchanges

I have a problem with `ngOnChanges` not being fired for a child component after data is being manipulated in parent via subscribe method.

Basically my main component looks like this:

```
public imageGroups: IImageGroup[];
public status$: Observable<ModelStatusesModel>;


public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (Boolean(this.treeData)) {
    this.imageGroups = this.treeDataService.convertImageGroups(this.treeData);
    this.status$ = this.updateStatus();
    this.status$.subscribe((status: ModelStatusesModel) => {
      this.treeDataService.updateStatus(this.imageGroups, status); // this function makes changes to this.imageGroups
      console.log('subscribe happened');
    });
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
...
<ul class="treeview-nodes-wrapper">
  <treeview-branch *ngFor="let group of (imageGroups)"
                                          [group]="group"></treeview-branch>
</ul>
...
```

The branch has also ngOnChnages:

```
public ngOnChanges(): void {
  this._currentNodeDisabled = this.group.isDisabled;
  console.log(this.group); //returns isDisables as true
  console.log(this.group.isDisabled); //returns false
  console.log(this._currentNodeDisabled); //returns false
}
```

When I run my application this is the result in the console:

```
{ ... isDisabled: true ...},
false
false
subscribe happened
```

I was also trying to surround the call inside my subscription in a `ngZone.run` but without any success. Do you have any idea how to tell angular that `ngOnChanges` in the child triggered?

**EDIT:** What works for me is creating a property in the parent component (`public change = false;`) then toggling this property inside my subscribe method and giving it as an input to my children elements. That gets picked up as a change. Even though this solves my problem, it looks more like a very hacky way of writing the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913255/ngonchanges-not-firing-when-attribute-changed-by-observable-subscrption

Comment: @MarcHernández I can't see how that would be applied to my problem as I am dealing with a very different structure

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of ngOnChanges being triggered when an input value `changes`, and with objects that are passed by reference the modification of their properties does not explicitly change the thing being passed down. The solution is often times to do a clone, ...spread operator, or reassign to the property that is being passed down in the parent's [input].

Your solution of having an additional input that changes to a new value to trigger ngOnChanges works as well, it's a bit of a workaround but that's web dev. just remember if you set the property to true then true again it won't trigger, so a count variable may work better (it's kinda hacky).

Answer (score 1):

Doing a clone via JSON.parse solved my problem in a cleaner way than toggling a variable :

```
...
  this.status$.subscribe((status: ModelStatusesModel) => {
    this.treeDataService.updateStatus(this.imageGroups, status);
    triggerChange();
  });
...

private triggerChange() {
    this.imageGroups = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.imageGroups));
}
```